# Calling scikit-learn functions from C++

Tags: python, c++, opencv, boost, scikit-learn

Is there way to call scikit-learn's functions from c++? I have the rest of most my code in C++ with opencv. I would like to be able use the classifiers scikit-learn provides. As far as I understand, there's no easy  way - I need to use boost::python or swig. I also came across this project (https://github.com/spillai/numpy-opencv-converter) which shows interop between numpy arrays <==> cv::Mat objects, but I know only how to use to call C++ code from my python script, not the other way around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following up from the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30237780/1933672), There seem to be two approaches today to solve the problem

1. A mechanism to wrap python into C++ and call it: A modern approach
   to do this is with [PyBind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11)
2. Use native C++ ML libraries - [MLPack](https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack) seems to be the gold standard, and [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) for vision based ML.

Answer (score 10):

Have you looked at native C++ libraries like [shogun](http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/) and [mlpack](http://www.mlpack.org/)? These might be much easier for you to use.

Comment: Please, share if there are any new C++ tools since your answer in 2015, thanks.

Comment: Does Shogun support DBSCAN?

Comment: @Avrdan it doesn't look like it but MLPack does: https://www.mlpack.org/doc/stable/cli_documentation.html#mlpack_dbscan just check both of their documentations.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in a pretty straightforward way, by including python headers and just calling your python script and/or scikit methods via Py* wrappers.

See https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#pure-embedding for a thorough example.

Answer (score 0):

For [some supported models](https://onnx.ai/sklearn-onnx/supported.html), it may be possible to convert them to ONNX runtime an run that via C++.

1. convert the sklearn model (pipeline) to ONNX (see [here](https://onnx.ai/sklearn-onnx/)) and
2. run ONNX-runtime in C++ (see [here](https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/get-started/with-cpp.html))